# Combobox filled with FontFamilies set SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selecteditem, font-family

i have a problem:
I want to make little Note Application for personal use. In this little Scratchpad i have a settings menu with a combobox for all the installed Fonts.

FontFamilyDrop.ItemsSource = Fonts.SystemFontFamilies;

Now i want to save and read this value in my settings.ini file.
Writing the value works perfectly by converting the SelectedItem to a string.

When the user opens the settings menu, i want to preload the current font and i dont know how to set the SelectedItem property by just having a string for lets say "Lucida Console".

Comment: I do not know if this is best approach but do a `foreach` and look at the types and see if the `string` `contains` the one you are looking for.  If so, make that the selected item.

Comment: ok i'll try tomorrow, thought of that too but i thought there would be something easier. Searching for an easy solution i found Array.IndexOf(array, value); but it doesnt seem to work with fonts :(

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this one now:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= FontFamilyArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    Title = FontFamilyArray[i].ToString();
}
```

The problem is that it doesnt work. It throws an exception.

Now the thing that makes me confused is, that when i fill in "2" instead of i like this:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= FontFamilyArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    Title = FontFamilyArray[2].ToString();
}
```

This way it works perfectly... Does anyone know why?

Comment: It would depend on what `FontFamilyArray.GetLength(0)` equals.  Set a breakpoint in the for loop and ensure you are checking the value 2.

Comment: Thx problem solved now, it was a simple overflow that shows up in a crash instead of readable compiler warning